# Need to list countries by top 25 in a category with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, list

I am trying to list countries by top 25 in a specific category and year in sql but I am having trouble figuring out how to do that.

For example I have the categories Country and economic freedom. I want to list the 25 countries in economic freedom in the year 2016. How would I do that?

Countries is a varchar and Economic freedom is also varchar ex.(3.60)
This is for Microsoft Sql Server.

Comment: Give sample data and your expected result..

Comment: You can use TOP(@count) -When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows;

Comment: Shouldn't *economic freedom* be numeric for 1-25 ranking?

Answer (score 0):

`Select EconomicFreedom,count(*) from table group by EconomicFreedom having count(*) <=25 order by Countries desc;`

> Group by is the major step

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a regular SELECT TOP with an ORDER BY clause. Please beware that you need to convert Economic freedom to a numeric data type, otherwise 4 > 10, because 4 > 1. Given provided information, this should be your query, if Year is a column as well.

```
SELECT TOP 25 [Country], [Economic freedom]
FROM Table
WHERE [Year] = 2016
ORDER BY CAST([Economic freedom] as float) DESC
```

Comment: Why use a float?

Comment: It's just my goto numeric data type when not knowing the number of decimals etc. We just need [Economic freedom] to be numeric for correct sorting.